# WPF List - ListItem Visibility

Tags: wpf, list, listitem

Greetings, 
I have a FlowDocument where List control is placed. Inside this list I have some ListItem. Is there any way to set some kind of Visibility for specific ListItem? I don't see a coressponding Property like Visibility for ListItem. When I set fontsize="0.1" then application hangs (it goes into infinite loop).

Comment: FontSize="0.1" to hide a list item?  Boy, is that rich.  Read this http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Poke-a-Dot.aspx

Comment: hey, that is the reason why I asked about visibility property? fontsize=0.1 was just for test!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set visibility of the ListItem using a binding on the `ListItemTemplate`, but a better approach would probably be to filter the list that you're binding to.  Is there a reason that your list contains items that you don't want to display in the list?